# Adding a Like Button which doesn't require User Model

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, social-media-like

I'm trying to add a like button to my rails site so I've looked at the acts_as_votable gem and the Active Record Reputation System gem. However, both of these require a User Model (I think), and I want to make the like button something that anyone can click whether they are signed in or not.

Is there a way to make one of these gems function like that, or will I have to create the voting system from scratch? Also, if I do have to do it from scratch, some guidelines to approaching it would be helpful.

Comment: What exactly are people liking?

Comment: A model named "Images"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create another model called `Like` and then create a `one to many association` between `Image` and `Like`.

```
rails g resource Like image_id:integer
```

then update your database by running

```
rake db:migrate
```

then you'll want to create the association.

```
# like.rb
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image
end

# image.rb
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :likes
end
```

Then when someone clicks on the like button, you'll want to create a `new Like` with the `id` of the `Image`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a very simple system where anyone can upvote an 'image', you can put a simple counter on each image.

For example, assuming you're using a sql flavor database that has a table called `images` right now, make a migration with a `change` method something like this:

```
def change
  add_column :images, :likes, :integer, default: 0
end
```

Then in your `ImagesController` or whatever you're calling it, make an action such as

```
def upvote
  image = Image.find(params[:id]) # in Rails 4, using strong params, this would look a bit different.
  image.update_attributes(likes: image.likes + 1)
  render json: image
end
```

There is a lot I'm leaving out, but you may get the idea from this that upvoting without users is actually extremely simple.  It only gets complicated once you start trying to keep track of who liked what.